# Is there a way to change the font size in MFMailCompose?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to send a text file in the body of my email, using MFMailComposeController.  Is there a way to change the font size?

```
NSString *file = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `MFMailComposeViewController`'s `-setMessageBody:isHTML:` for starters. If you specify a message body that *is* HTML, then you can also include CSS markup specified in an included `<style>` section for whatever font styling you like, among other things.